# How to make Terminal forget all old open windows when quit?

Tags: terminal, window-manager

This is not exactly [the question asked here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/100790/shutdown-from-terminal-without-remembering-open-windows), but the end result is the same that I am trying to solve.

I have terminal set (Settings, Shell tab) to "Close the window" when the shell exits, and to "Never" ask before closing.  But whenever the Mac is shut down from a Cron job, when it boots back up again and runs a Terminal script at boot, the old window(s) reappear, resulting over time in Terminal having dozens of windows open for no reason.

Is there any way to get Terminal to *actually* close its windows when it exits so that they will not reopen again after a restart?

**EDIT:  To illustrate the issue, I've left the machine alone for a couple weeks, not closing any Terminal windows etc.  It reboots every night.  Here is how Terminal looks on it right now, I've stacked all the old idle windows here, and the newest active window is the topmost.**

[image: Look at all these old Terminal windows!]

Comment: You'd either have to close the windows first, or change the OS preference to re-open application widows to No.  Your login session is being torn down before the shell(s) exit.

Answer (score 2):

You'd either have to close the windows first, or uncheck the OS preference to re-open application windows.

Your login session is being torn down before the shell(s) exit.

[image]

Comment: Yep, in my case turning that option off solved it.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Sorry, I stand corrected.  This has not solved the problem.  Terminal still opens with an extra window every single time the machine reboots.  =(

Comment: Well, if it runs a script in Terminal, you're kinda going to get a window, I would think.

Comment: That's not what I mean.  I get a window, and then I *also* get the window where the script runs.  There is always an additional window.

Comment: I added an image to my original post, in case my explanation here wasn't clear.